# getting error while using nltk library python even after updating nltk in python 3.7.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have tried from un-installing to re-installing of jupyter notebook and also separately installed pycharm and tried working using it but still it shows error and does not install gensim properly.I also installed virtual studio and vc2015+ libraries and other support libraries from visual studio.
most of the time the usage of simple libraries is good but i ' m not understanding after using pip,easy,conda and installing the libraries and updating it is still not working but scipy, sklearn are working properly

```
 ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-1d2184025e54> in <module>()
    ----> 1 import nltk

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py in <module>()
        127 # Import top-level functionality into top-level namespace
        128 
    --> 129 from nltk.collocations import *
        130 from nltk.decorators import decorator, memoize
        131 from nltk.featstruct import *

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py in <module>()
         38 from nltk.util import ngrams
         39 # these two unused imports are referenced in collocations.doctest
    ---> 40 from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures, QuadgramAssocMeasures
         41 from nltk.metrics.spearman import ranks_from_scores, spearman_correlation
         42 

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\__init__.py in <module>()
         14 """
         15 
    ---> 16 from nltk.metrics.scores import (
         17     accuracy,
         18     precision,

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\scores.py in <module>()
         16 
         17 try:
    ---> 18     from scipy.stats.stats import betai
         19 except ImportError:
         20     betai = None

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>()
        343 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
        344 
    --> 345 from .stats import *
        346 from .distributions import *
        347 from .morestats import *

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>()
        169 import scipy.special as special
        170 import scipy.linalg as linalg
    --> 171 from . import distributions
        172 from . import mstats_basic
        173 from ._distn_infrastructure import _lazywhere

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py in <module>()
          8 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
          9 
    ---> 10 from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
         11                                     rv_frozen)
         12 

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in <module>()
         14 import warnings
         15 
    ---> 16 from scipy.misc import doccer
         17 from ._distr_params import distcont, distdiscrete
         18 from scipy._lib._util import check_random_state, _lazywhere, _lazyselect

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py in <module>()
         66 from numpy import who as _who, source as _source, info as _info
         67 import numpy as np
    ---> 68 from scipy.interpolate._pade import pade as _pade
         69 from scipy.special import (comb as _comb, logsumexp as _lsm,
         70         factorial as _fact, factorial2 as _fact2, factorialk as _factk)

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py in <module>()
        173 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
        174 
    --> 175 from .interpolate import *
        176 from .fitpack import *
        177 

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py in <module>()
         30 from . import _ppoly
         31 from .fitpack2 import RectBivariateSpline
    ---> 32 from .interpnd import _ndim_coords_from_arrays
         33 from ._bsplines import make_interp_spline, BSpline
         34 

    interpnd.pyx in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd()

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py in <module>()
         92 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
         93 
    ---> 94 from .kdtree import *
         95 from .ckdtree import *
         96 from .qhull import *

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\kdtree.py in <module>()
          6 import numpy as np
          7 from heapq import heappush, heappop
    ----> 8 import scipy.sparse
          9 
         10 __all__ = ['minkowski_distance_p', 'minkowski_distance',

    ~\Anaconda301\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py in <module>()
        239 
        240 # For backward compatibility with v0.19.
    --> 241 from . import csgraph
        242 
        243 __all__ = [s for s in dir() if not s.startswith('_')]

    ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to answer this question, we may need more information about how you reached this point. What OS are you on? What steps did you follow to install nltk? Do you mean Visual Studio? etc.

Comment: [Can I ask questions about installation in SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so) Software tools commonly used by programmers and is
**a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.**

Comment: OS is windows 10ci have tried installing and reinstalling libraries using pip, easy and conda for pycharm, anaconda also tried doing the same for Jupiter and pycharm and also heard that the problem will get fixed if you install proper 2014 c++ vc so installed virtual studio and installed all support system for python, pycharm and other numpy libraries like emaildata so I installed all libraries of vc2015.   Thankyou guys for responding.